# Creating sublists from a list based on another list in python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists: l1 and l2, which are shown below.

```
l1 = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
l2 = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

I want to sublist l1 into a list of lists based on values in l2, like below, one for '0' and one for '1'

```
[[0, 1, 1], [1, 0]]
```

this basically says, for 0 in l2, there are three values in l1 and for 1 in l2, there are two values in l1.

Is there a simple python way to do this?

EDIT: Here is what I have done to solve. This works well, but seems clunky and strange looking. I am looking for a more elegant solution.

```
d = [[],[]]
for i in range(len(l2)):
    d[l2[i]].append(l1[i])
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what precisely is the problem with it? This isn't a code writing service.

Comment: Edited my comment to include what I have done thus far

Answer (score 3):

```
[[l1[n] for n, l2s in enumerate(l2) if l2s == element] for element in set(l2)]
```

Something like this might do the trick. `set` is just a bit faster.

Answer (score 2):

Basically your same algorithm, but a little more Pythonic.  `zip` iterates the lists in parallel, giving you the first items, then the 2nd items, etc.:

```
l1 = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
l2 = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]

L = [[],[]]
for a,b in zip(l1,l2):
    L[b].append(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed that you might have an arbitrary number of subsets defined by their "keys" in `l2`, and also that your keys are both sortable and hashable:

```
def partition(keys, values):
    unique_keys = sorted(set(keys))
    for key in unique_keys:
        yield [val for idx, val in enumerate(values) if keys[idx] == key]
    return
```

Using your two lists, `l1` and `l2`, you could produce your list-of-lists like this:

```
list(partition(keys=l2, values=l1))
```

(Note that, technically, a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) is a function of sets, not lists, but I think it gets the idea across.)